# Replace values, pandas.___

Tags: pandas, replace

I have a dataset from a company with a gender column. This has 3 values: male, Female and Other. I would like to replace "Other"values for  50% female, 50 % male( more or less) How can I do it?

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the same as your previous question [Missing values /pandas, Gender columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69499108/15497888) what about the previous answer did not work?